# Finding all checkboxes are checked in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a collection of checkboxes

```
 <input id="1" class="paid" type="checkbox" />
 <input id="2" class="paid" type="checkbox" />
 <input id="3" class="paid" type="checkbox" />
 <input id="4" class="paid" type="checkbox" />
```

I would like to write some jQuery to check if all checkboxes are checked then perform an action but how?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (!$('input.paid[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length)
    do('stuff');
```

This will check if there are any that are unchecked, and do stuff if there aren't (i.e. they are all checked).

Comment: any modern way to do the same thing

Answer (score 2):

I think there would be a good feature in jquery an `are` function:

```
jQuery.fn.are = function(selector) {
return !!selector && this.filter(selector).length == this.length;
};
```

Usage:

```
if($('input.paid[type=checkbox]').are(':checked'))
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9s2vA/

I have found this function at 
http://api.jquery.com/is/
written by Tgr , when I was checking if this exists.