# How to check if all checkboxes inside a div are checked using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this fails:

```
var all_checkboxes = $('#myDiv input[type="checkbox"]');

if (all_checkboxes.is(':checked')) {
   alert('they are all checked');
}
```

it alerts they are all checked even if just one and not all is checked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all checkboxes are checked in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497945/finding-all-checkboxes-are-checked-in-jquery)

Answer (score 10):

you can check if all your checkboxes are checked like this:

```
var all_checkboxes = $('#myDiv input[type="checkbox"]');

if (all_checkboxes.length === all_checkboxes.filter(":checked").length) {
  alert('they are all checked');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check that none of them are unchecked:

```
if (all_checkboxes.not(":checked").length === 0)
```

Comment: But he wants to see if all are checked, not unchecked

Comment: @voigtan: If none of them are unchecked, that means that all of them are checked.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a same class "myClass" to all the check boxes and then:

```
let areAllChecked = !$('.myClass').not(':checked').length; //'true' if all checked
```