# Checking checkboxes in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Hello i'm trying to check if the checkboxes are checked or not. However my checkboxes are created using a for loop and the value of each checkbox is actually the same.

Code is as follows:

```
{% for keyword in keyword_list %}
    {% if keyword.keyword_name == userprofile.keywords_subscribed  %}
        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="keywords" value="keywords"/>   {{keyword.keyword_name}}<br />
    {% else %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="keywords"  />   {{keyword.keyword_name}}<br />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Jquery code as follows:

```
<h2>Price of subscriptions</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/fc3/charts/FusionCharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function popup(){
        {% for price in price_list %}
            alert({{price.price_of_each_keyword}})
        {% endfor %}
    }
    function DoTheCheck() { if(document.cb2.checked == true)
                { alert('box2 is checked'); }
    }

    </script>
```

At the moment this is all i can think of.

So how do i use jquery to iterate through the checkboxes and check to see if they are checked?

I found some examples on the web but most of them actually created individual checkbox names for their code and this makes it easier to use jquery to check them.

Appreciate any help i can get.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us the surrounding HTML (parent objects).  With what you've shown, there isn't enough to know what jQuery would work because you input tags aren't uniquely identifiable.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all checkboxes are checked in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497945/finding-all-checkboxes-are-checked-in-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a list of all checked checkboxes in the site with this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
```

**SHORT**

As mentioned from Craig, there is a short version available as well:

```
$(':checkbox:checked')
```

**COUNT**

And if you want to know the no of checked checkboxes, simply do this:

```
$(':checkbox:checked').length
```

Comment: +1 there is a short form `:checkbox` selector as well that is written like this `$(':checkbox:checked')` to get the checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna loop thru all checkbox on the page

You could give them a class and loop like this

```
$('.yourClass').each(function(i, obj) {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
{

your code

}

});
```

Comment: what if i wanted to count the number of checked boxes?

Comment: of those you created with the loop or all checkbox on the page? If you want all checkbox, the other Marc has the good way to do it

Comment: found the answer. Just needed to use the function.length cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

Marc has a good answer, but if you want to go through each one and check then the following will do that.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked")){
         alert($(this).attr("name")+ " is checked");
     } else {
         alert($(this).attr("name")+ " is not checked");
     }
   });
```

hope that helps!

Comment: thanks ehudokai! any idea on how i can check the number of boxes checked?

Comment: there you go: `$(':checkbox:checked').length`

Comment: `this.checked` is more efficient and (in my opinion) easier to read than `$(this).is(":checked")`. Same goes for `this.name`...